# catch button event from usercontrol

Tags: wpf, button, user-controls, click

I have a button name mybutton that is a part of a usercontrol X.
I made another usercontrol Y that holds X (X is part of it).

I want to catch in Y the event of mybutton when clicked.

How can I do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following code. It's the same with `UserControl` instead of `Grid`. The `Click` event is routed up the visual tree, read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx).

```
<Grid Button.Click="Button_Clicked">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Save" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>


private void Button_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //your code here
}
```

Comment: I will explain myself: I have in one xaml: <Usercontrol name="X"><button click="x_click"></button> now I create in another xaml <Usercontrol Name=Y><X></X></UserControl>. how can I get the x_click event in code behind of usercontrol Y ? Thanks a lot

Comment: It's no difference, attach a `Button.Click="Button_Clicked"` in your Y `UserControl` like this: `<Usercontrol Name=Y><X Button.Click="Button_Clicked"></X></UserControl>`

Comment: Thanks a lot. working. Just for my knowledge: what about if I have two buttons in X ? I should put in "Button_Clicked" a switch case according to button name ? or is an elegant way to do it ?

Comment: It's better to use [RoutedCommands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx) if you have multiple `Buttons`. In this case you can give each `Button` a different `Command` and set up a handler for each of them. The principle is the same - the `Command` is routed up the visual tree.